# UrlSession closure code not called after receiving data

Tags: swift, urlsession

I have a UrlSession that calls a web service, and should receive a users data, which is then processed. The data processing closure is never entered though. I have checked to make sure that the url created returns the expected data. Please see my code below:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct DbCustomer: Codable, Identifiable
{
    var id: String
    var user_name: String
    var pass_word: String
    var fullname: String
}

class LunchboxViewModel: ObservableObject
{
    
    @AppStorage("loggedIn") var loggedIn: Bool = false
    @AppStorage("username") var username: String = ""
    @AppStorage("password") var password: String = ""
    @AppStorage("fullname") var fullname: String = ""
    @AppStorage("userid") var userId: String = ""

    func loginInUser(username: String) -> Bool
    {
        var urlComponents = URLComponents()
        urlComponents.scheme = "http"
        urlComponents.host = "www.venndor.co.uk"
        urlComponents.path = "/logindo.php"
        urlComponents.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "username", value: username)
        ]
        guard let url = urlComponents.url else {
            fatalError("Invalid URL")
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        
        /* the code below is never executed*/

            guard let data = data else{ return}
            do{
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.dataDecodingStrategy = .base64
                let decodedData =  try decoder.decode([DbCustomer].self, from: data)
                self.username = decodedData[0].user_name
                self.password = decodedData[0].pass_word
                self.userId = decodedData[0].id
                self.fullname = decodedData[0].fullname
                self.loggedIn = true
            }catch let error{
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    if self.loggedInUser != nil
    {
        return true
    }
    else
    {
        print("no data")
        return false
    }
    }
}
```

Here is where the code is used, and called:

Here's the code!:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SignUpSignIn: View {
    
    @State var signUpProgress: Int = 0
    @State var fullname: String = ""
    @State var username: String = ""
    @State var companyname: String = ""
    @State var companydescription: String = ""
    @StateObject var viewModel: LunchboxViewModel = LunchboxViewModel()
    
    @State var loginSignUpOption: String? = nil
    
    //Sign Up Progress States
    /*
        0:  Welcome
        1:  Username
        2:  Full name
        3:  Company name
        4:  Company description
        5:  Complete
     */
    
    let transition: AnyTransition = .asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal: .move(edge: .leading))
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("", tag: "logIn", selection: $loginSignUpOption){ LunchboxTabView() }
        
        ZStack()
        {
            ZStack
            {
                switch signUpProgress
                {
                case 0:
                    welcomeScreen
                        .transition(transition)
                case 1:
                    addUsernameScreen
                        .transition(transition)
                case 2:
                    addNameScreen
                        .transition(transition)
                case 3:
                    addCompanyNameScreen
                        .transition(transition)
                case 4:
                    addCompanyDescriptionScreen
                        .transition(transition)
                default:
                    Text("Default")
                }
            }
            VStack()
            {
                Spacer()
                bottomButton
            }
            .padding(30)
        }
        .environmentObject(viewModel)
    }
}

struct SignUpSignIn_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SignUpSignIn()
            .background(.blue)
    }
}

// MARK: Components
extension SignUpSignIn
{
    var bottomButton: some View
    {
        Text(signUpProgress == 0 ? "Start": signUpProgress == 4 ? "Sign Up" : "Continue")
            .font(.headline)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .frame(height: 60)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(.white)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .onTapGesture {
                handleButtonPress()
            }
    }
    
    var welcomeScreen: some View
    {
        VStack(spacing: 40)
        {
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "tortoise")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            Text("Never miss them again!")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
            Text("With this app, you need never miss that sandwich lady, ice cream van, or other mobile vendor again!")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            Spacer()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    var addUsernameScreen: some View
    {
        VStack(spacing: 40)
        {
            Spacer()
            Text("Please enter a username")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
            TextField("Enter your username...", text: $username)
                .font(.headline)
                .frame(height: 55)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .background(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            Text("Enter any name you like as your username! If you have used the app before, and you want to use your old account, enter that username, and we'll do the rest!")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            Spacer()
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(30)
    }
    
    
    var addNameScreen: some View
    {
        VStack(spacing: 40)
        {
            Spacer()
            Text("Please enter your name")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
            TextField("Enter your name...", text: $fullname)
                .font(.headline)
                .frame(height: 55)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .background(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            Spacer()
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(30)
    }
    
    
    var addCompanyNameScreen: some View
    {
        VStack(spacing: 40)
        {
            Spacer()
            Text("Do you have a company?")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
            TextField("Enter your company's name...", text: $companyname)
                .font(.headline)
                .frame(height: 55)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .background(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            Text("If you have a company, and you want to use this app to alert your customers to your presence, just enter a name here. Leave it blank if not, and we'll sign you up right away!")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            Spacer()
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(30)
    }
    
    var addCompanyDescriptionScreen: some View
    {
        VStack(spacing: 40)
        {
            Spacer()
            Text("What does your company do?")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
            TextField("Enter a description of your company", text: $companydescription)
                .font(.headline)
                .lineLimit(10)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .frame(height: 200)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .background(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            Text("This is the last bit! Thank you for your patience! Just a quick check, and we'll have you signed up in no time!")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            Spacer()
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(30)
    }
    
}

// MARK: Functions
extension SignUpSignIn
{
    func handleButtonPress()
    {
        if signUpProgress == 1
        {
            if viewModel.loginInUser(username: username)
            {
                loginSignUpOption = "logIn"
            }
        }
        if companyname == "" && signUpProgress > 2
        {
            let newUser = DbCustomer(id: "0", user_name: username, pass_word: "", fullname: fullname)
            viewModel.signUpUser(user: newUser)
            loginSignUpOption = "logIn"
            return
        }
        if signUpProgress == 5
        {
            let newUser = DbCustomer(id: "0", user_name: username, pass_word: "", fullname: fullname)
            let newCompany = DbVendor(id: "0", company_name: companyname, description: companydescription, customer_id: "0")
            viewModel.signUpUserWithCompany(user: newUser, company: newCompany)
            loginSignUpOption = "logIn"
            return
        }
        else
        {
            withAnimation(.spring())
            {
                signUpProgress += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check data not being nil?

Comment: It doesn't let me check data - it executes the URLSession dataTask, and then goes to resume. I have placed breakpoints at guard let data = data and at the decoder line inside the do, and they are never reached.

I have checked manually that the URL contains the correct data by printing the URL in the console, and pasting it into a browser.

Comment: try `print("no data")` before return.

Comment: Tested it and it works just fine. Please delete your comment with that username as a login succeeds even without password but the response will reveal your password.

Comment: That's bizarre! Maybe I'll try deleting the app and clean the build folder!

Comment: In addition please share where instance of `LunchboxViewModel` lives and how you call `logInUser`. Possibly this goes out of scope.

Comment: I have inserted the code in the original code post. Note: I  have changed the function to return bool

Comment: It has started to work now... I moved the place where I initialise the LunchboxViewModel - as you said - it must have been out of scope somehow

Answer (score 0):

Probably `data` is nil.

Put a break point at line that you get `guard let data = data else{ return}` to debug value of `data`